# RegExp - Find the last match, with left whitespace

Tags: regex

I'd like to get the last match from the string provided. Currently, it is:
`2 + 5 + 8e+d`. It should select the second `+`, out of three.

The RegExp is `[(\+\s)](?=[^(\+\s)]*$)` and it selects the third `+`.

---

I know this problem is very simple, however, none, of these worked:

1. `[(\+\s)](?=[^(\+\s)]*$)`
2. `[(\+\s)](?=[^(\+)]*$)`
3. `[+](?=[^(+\s)]*$)`

The original RegExp was the following: `[-+*/](?=[^-+*/]*$)` and it selected either the last `+`, `-`, `/`, or `*`. Basically, I'd like to convert it so it selects `" +", " -", " *", " /"`.

Last and with the whitespace (one) in the left side.

You can test it here: https://regexr.com/3lc1a.

Comment: I'd like left side whitespace, not right.

Comment: `\s[-+\/*)](?!.*[-+\/*]\s)`, is it good?

Comment: Ok, then use [`/\s[-+\/*](?!.*\s[-+\/*])/`](https://regex101.com/r/RJslgQ/1/)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Should I upvote this comment or will you post the answer?

Comment: Sorry, if you are only provided one string, then why use regexp at all?  Can you explain the rules (and give some _different_ examples) to illustrate how we can composte different strings to know how to match them properly?

Comment: @LuisColorado It's already answered, just check the answers and my article one more time so you can understand it clearly. Why RegExp? I'm working on a calculator project where is a lot of code and in order to detect one thing I have to use `match` function. The RegExp comes into play here.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the people is good enough to make an effort to understand you, but this doesn't mean your question is well formulated.  Putting only (or outside SO) the information makes your question short lived only, while the purpose of SO is not only in helping you, but anybody that happens to have the same question in the future.  Only a single string is not enough to characterize a possible infinite set of strings... so despite the question has been answered already, and you have selected the answer as the good one, your question continues to be a poor one.

Comment: Read about _How to ask_ as recommended in the welcome to SO, as you seem to have little or no experience in how to deal in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/\s[-+\/*](?!.*\s[-+\/*])/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RJslgQ/1/)

**Details**

- `\s` - a whitespace
- `[-+\/*]` - a `-`, `+`, `/` or `*`
- `(?!.*\s[-+\/*])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `-`, `+`, `/` or `*` after any 0+ chars other than line break chars immediately to the right of the current position.

If there can be multiple lines in the input, replace `.*` with `[^]*` or `[\s\S]*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^.*\K [\/*+-]
```

[The Demo](https://regex101.com/r/84Z2Ov/2)